# Symfony 2 UserProvider based on slow external API: How to cache / speed it up?

Tags: php, performance, security, symfony, caching

the problem (in a nutshell) is:

Our current solution way too slow.

1. The Symfony Security component reloads the user on every pageview.
2. Users are loaded from our own UserProvider that accesses a slow external API.

The first idea coming to our minds is:

We could cache information coming from the external API in a local database or memcache.

My questions:

1. Are there any bundles out there that could help us achieve this?
2. Should we deal with all of the caching in our own UserProvider?
3. Is it maybe a better idea to put users that need to be cached into a doctrine entity and use a chain provider to load them from doctrine first? In this case, how do we handle a limited lifetime of user objects?
4. How about not caching anything but just writing our providers refresh function so that it only reloads users if the last reloads happend too long back?

Any other ideas on how to do this efficiently?

Cheers,

Timon

Comment: is your external api a standadised one like oauth or custom?

Comment: Hi Udan, the API is a custom one. We already have a client for it and a user provider that accesses it, so the question is really just about getting it to perform. Cheers, Timon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither cache nor chained providers are a "perfect" solution as you have to implement logic which invalidates the user when changes in the external provider occur (e.g. changed password). Which, if I understand right, would require you to check against the API frequently. Seems like you have to compromise between performance and checking for updates frequently one way or the other.

That being said, I assume you already have a custom user provider which reads users via API and I don't see anything wrong with adding a cache as a dependency to that or maybe create a second CacheApiUserProvider next to your UserProvider, so you can switch between them when you are having troubles with your cache backend. I don't think there's an additonial bundle necessary for that, but you might want to look for caching-bundles.

I don't see how a chained provider as you propose in (3) would help you, as you would just have the same limitations, i.e. frequently check for changes in your external provider, just as with the cache. If I had to choose, I would use the CachedProvider as it is pretty much what you are trying to do, a more complicated chain provider would just conceal what problem you wanted to solve in the first place and confuse future maintainers (in short: keep it simple).

Depending on what the API provides you might be able to run a worker in the background which automatically fetches new users and changes to existing users from the API and moves them to a (local) database, but in that case I wouldn't bother setting up a chained provider and just rely on the database to be up to date.